# Passar uma list para uma view para obter via JavaScript

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um método *Index*, onde ele recebe um parâmetro, faz uma consulta e retorna uma lista.

Preciso passar essa lista junto com a *view* ou obter essa lista de alguma outra forma, para que eu possa acessar lista via *angularJS*.

```
   public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
        _check.NumberOfregistrationUser = id;

     // variável que guarda o resultado da minha consulta
       var list = GetUserByNumberOfregistration(_check.NumberOfregistrationUser);

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Você tem várias opções aí, mas ao trabalhar com AngularJS, geralmente se consulta os dados do servidor com chamadas HTTP. Se este for o caso você vai precisar de outra _action_ só para retornar os dados para o cliente. Caso contrário, você pode colocar os dados na ViewBag ou então retorná-los como modelo da _view_ e serializá-los lá. Pra todos os efeitos as duas últimas opções me parecem bem ruins e um péssimo uso de um framework _frontend_ como o AngularJS. Bem, pra você receber uma resposta, é preciso [edit] a pergunta e esclarecer o que pretende fazer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public JsonResult MinhaLista(int id)
{
  _check.NumberOfregistrationUser = id;

     // variável que guarda o resultado da minha consulta
    var list = GetUserByNumberOfregistration(_check.NumberOfregistrationUser);

  return Json(new { nomeMeuObjRetorno = list  }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Assim você pode acessar sua lista com Jquery, javascript ou angular como uma simples chamada ajax e terá um retorno em obj.